# How to import csv files as data for bootstrapping

Tags: java

I'm trying to import a csv file to my grails project, what I'm trying to do is to build a map based on that csv file which is a list of countries (countries.csv) and use the map as a bootstrap data.

any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming (perhaps incorrectly!) that you mean that you once you have the csv file in your project, you want your program to read it and use the data contained in it.

There are a number of OSS CSV parsers out there.  For starters:

- [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
- [Ostermiller CSV](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html)
- [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/)
- [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/)

Find one that does what you need.  It'll be easier than rolling your own, especially if your input file can have commas within strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Ostermiller Utilities](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html)